# Python Unix time doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, utc, unix-timestamp

In Python, using calendar.timegm(), I get a 10 digit result for a unix timestamp. When I put this into Javscript's setTime() function, it comes up with a date in 1970. It evidently needs a unix timestamp that is 13 digits long. How can this happen? Are they both counting from the same date?

How can I use the same unix timestamp between these two languages?

In Python:

```
In [60]: parseddate.utctimetuple()
Out[60]: (2009, 7, 17, 1, 21, 0, 4, 198, 0)
In [61]: calendar.timegm(parseddate.utctimetuple())
Out[61]: 1247793660
```

In Firebug:

```
>>> var d = new Date(); d.setTime(1247793660); d.toUTCString()
"Thu, 15 Jan 1970 10:36:55 GMT"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't passing these dates in a format besides UTC(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

timegm is based on Unix's [gmtime()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_gmtime.htm) method, which return seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Javascripts [setTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setTime.asp) method is milliseconds since that date.  You'll need to multiply your seconds times 1000 to convert to the format expected by Javascript.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a couple of python methods I use to convert to and from javascript/datetime.

```
def to_datetime(js_timestamp):
    return  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(js_timestamp/1000)

def js_timestamp_from_datetime(dt):
    return 1000 * time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
```

In javascript you would do:

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(js_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you possibly mixing up seconds-since-1970 with milliseconds-since-1970?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) works with milliseconds, you should multiply the Python unix time by 1000.

```
var unixTimestampSeg = 1247793660;
var date = new Date(unixTimestampSeg*1000);
```